# Tensorflow: NaN for custom softmax

Tags: python, tensorflow

Simply exchanging the **nn.softmax** function for a combination which uses **tf.exp**, keeping everything else like it was, causes not only the gradients to contain NaN but also the intermediate variable **s**. I have no idea why this is.

```
tempX = x
tempW = W
tempMult = tf.matmul(tempX, W)
s = tempMult + b

#! ----------------------------
#p = tf.nn.softmax(s)
p = tf.exp(s) / tf.reduce_sum(tf.exp(s), axis=1)
#!------------------------------


myTemp = y*tf.log(p)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(myTemp, reduction_indices=1)) + mylambda*tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(W,W))

grad_W, grad_b = tf.gradients(xs=[W, b], ys=cost)

new_W = W.assign(W - tf.multiply(learning_rate, grad_W))
new_b = b.assign(b - tf.multiply(learning_rate, grad_b))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer

`tf.exp(s)` easily overflows for large **s**.  That's the main reason that `tf.nn.softmax` doesn't actually use that equation but does *something equilivent* to it (according to the docs).

## Discussion

When I rewrote your softmax function to

```
p = tf.exp(s) / tf.reshape( tf.reduce_sum(tf.exp(s), axis=1), [-1,1] )
```

It worked without a problem.

Here is a fully working python 2.7 implementation that uses a hand-crafted softmax and works (using the reshape function)

```
# -- imports --
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# np.set_printoptions(precision=1) reduces np precision output to 1 digit
np.set_printoptions(precision=2, suppress=True)

# -- constant data --
x = [[0., 0.], [1., 1.], [1., 0.], [0., 1.]]
y_ = [[1., 0.], [1., 0.], [0., 1.], [0., 1.]]

# -- induction --
# 1x2 input -> 2x3 hidden sigmoid -> 3x1 sigmoid output

# Layer 0 = the x2 inputs
x0 = tf.constant(x, dtype=tf.float32)
y0 = tf.constant(y_, dtype=tf.float32)

# Layer 1 = the 2x3 hidden sigmoid
m1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([2, 3], minval=0.1, maxval=0.9, dtype=tf.float32))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([3], minval=0.1, maxval=0.9, dtype=tf.float32))
h1 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x0, m1) + b1)

# Layer 2 = the 3x2 softmax output
m2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([3, 2], minval=0.1, maxval=0.9, dtype=tf.float32))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([2], minval=0.1, maxval=0.9, dtype=tf.float32))
h2 = tf.matmul(h1, m2) + b2
y_out = tf.exp(h2) / tf.reshape( tf.reduce_sum(tf.exp(h2), axis=1) , [-1,1] )


# -- loss --

# loss : sum of the squares of y0 - y_out
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y0 - y_out))

# training step : gradient decent (1.0) to minimize loss
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss)


# -- training --
# run 500 times using all the X and Y
# print out the loss and any other interesting info
#with tf.Session() as sess:
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print "\nloss"
for step in range(500):
    sess.run(train)
    if (step + 1) % 100 == 0:
        print sess.run(loss)

results = sess.run([m1, b1, m2, b2, y_out, loss])
labels = "m1,b1,m2,b2,y_out,loss".split(",")
for label, result in zip(*(labels, results)):
    print ""
    print label
    print result

print ""
```

Perhaps your initial values for M and b are too *large*.  I tried re-running my above code but with with weights initialized to large numbers and I was able to reproduce your NaN issue.